# Caeser Cipher Code, Lower Case not working

Tags: python-3.x

So I am trying to make a Caesar cipher code which includes encrypt. So far, I have been able to succeed in these aspects, but I have not been able to figure out how have my code use lower cases. For instance, when you enter a message (we'll use HelLO with a key of 1), it will return IFMMP. The problem I have with this is that it does not return the lower case letters as lower case, but instead as upper case. I was wondering if someone could please help me figure out my issue. Thank you!
PS: This is code for python3.
    ABCs=

["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

```
ans= input("Do you wish to encrypt, decrypt or brute force?")


if ans== "encrypt":
  msg=input("Enter your message:")
  key=int(input("Enter the key number (1-26)"))

  uncodedmsg= list(msg)
  for i in range (0, len(uncodedmsg)):
    letter=uncodedmsg[i]
    if letter  not in ABCs:
      i+=1
    else:
      letter2= ABCs.index(letter)
      letter3= letter2+key
      uncodedmsg[i]= ABCs[letter3%26] 
  messageend="".join(uncodedmsg)
  print ("Your translated text is:" + messageend )
```

Comment: Also my abc list didnt go into the code for some reason, oops. It is in the help box above though, sorry this is my first time on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
uncodedmsg[i] = ABCs[letter3 % 26]
```

You are take the modulus of both upper and lowers so your answer will never be above 26, therefore you will never get a lowercase.

What you could do is branch UpperCase and LowerCase with something like this:

```
ABCs = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
abcs = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

if letter.isupper():
    letter2 = ABCs.index(letter)
    letter3 = letter2 + key
    uncodedmsg[i] = ABCs[letter3 % 26]
if letter.islower():
    letter2 = abcs.index(letter)
    letter3 = letter2 + key
    uncodedmsg[i] = abcs[letter3 % 26]
```